# KMeans Clustering: adding results to an initial dataset

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means

I defined features for the clustering with the help of KMeans:

```
x = df_1.iloc[:, np.r_[9:12,26:78]]
```

And run the code to get 6 clusters:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 6)
kmeans.fit(x)
```

Now I want in my initial dataset to have a column with number (df_1("new") =...) : 1 for group of data in cluster one, 2 for group of data in cluster two, etc.

how exactly do I do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`fit_predict(x)`](https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit_predict) (or `fit(x).predict(x)`), which returns the cluster for each sample.

> `fit_predict(X, y=None, sample_weight=None)`
> Compute cluster centers and predict cluster index for each sample.
> Convenience method; equivalent to calling fit(X) followed by predict(X).

So I suppose this would do:

```
df['cluster'] = kmeans.fit_predict(x)
```